# undefined method `belong_to' for User(no database connection):Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Hi I am trying to obtain the following relations in postgresDB.

Here are my relations
company has_many ratings , :through=> :users
ratings has_one :companies, :through=>:users
users belong_to :companies
users belong_to :rating

To obtain this I have created an following migrations in my DB

```
class AddCompanyIdToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :company_id, :integer
  end
end

class AddRatingIdToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :rating_id, :integer
  end
end
```

And add the relations to my Modals

I am getting the following error while running an server

```
`method_missing': undefined method `belong_to' for User(no database connection):Class (NoMethodError)
```

I am newbie to rails And can any one please tell me what is my problem. Do am doing right migrations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you're looking for is [`belongs_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to), not `belong_to`. There is no `belong_to` so your `user.rb` should look more like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :companies
  belongs_to :rating
  #-----^
```

Comment: Thank you it worked for me but I have got an this error class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many rating, :through=> :users   how to solve this

Comment: Right Now I have solved that problem. Thank you so much for your help.